Keycloak Can't connect to server
I am trying to build fastapi + keycloak app in docker-compose
My compose-file (Docker Compose version v2.18.1)
version: '3.8'

services:

  web:
    build: ./project/ui_backend
    command: uvicorn src.main:app --reload --workers 1 --host 0.0.0.0 --port 8000
    volumes:
      - ./project/ui_backend:/usr/src/app
    ports:
      - 8004:8000
    environment:
      - DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
      - DB_PORT=5432
      - DB_PASSWORD=postgres
      - DB_USER=postgres
      - DB_NAME=feast_backend_db
      - FEAST_SERVER_URL=http://127.0.0.1:8009
      - POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD=trust
    depends_on:
      - db
      - keycloak

  db:
    image: postgres:15.3
    expose:
      - 5432
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
      - POSTGRES_DB=feast_backend_db


  keycloak:
    image: "quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:latest"
    command: "start-dev --import-realm"
    restart: "on-failure"
    environment:
      - "KEYCLOAK_ADMIN=admin"
      - "KEYCLOAK_ADMIN_PASSWORD=admin"
    volumes:
      - ./realm-export.json:/opt/keycloak/data/import/myrealm.json
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
  
  

I have an error:
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/keycloak/keycloak_openid.py", line 257, in well_known
47_compose_feast-web-1       |     data_raw = self.connection.raw_get(URL_WELL_KNOWN.format(**params_path))
47_compose_feast-web-1       |                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
47_compose_feast-web-1       |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/keycloak/connection.py", line 247, in raw_get
47_compose_feast-web-1       |     raise KeycloakConnectionError("Can't connect to server (%s)" % e)
47_compose_feast-web-1       | keycloak.exceptions.KeycloakConnectionError: Can't connect to server (Invalid URL 'realms/fastapi-realm/.well-known/openid-configuration': No scheme supplied. Perhaps you meant https://realms/fastapi-realm/.well-known/openid-configuration?)

I was reading this answer Problem with connecting to Keycloak server using python-keycloak package but it did not help me
I think that there are no connectivity between fastapi and keycloak
My keycloak configuration:
from keycloak import KeycloakOpenID


# Keycloak configuration
KEYCLOAK_SERVER_URL = "localhost:8080" # was trying to replace with keycloak:8080
KEYCLOAK_REALM = "fastapi-realm"
KEYCLOAK_CLIENT_ID = "fastapi-client"
KEYCLOAK_CLIENT_SECRET ="None"  # Use None for public clients
ALGORITHM = "RS256"
TOKEN_URL = f"{KEYCLOAK_SERVER_URL}/realms/fastapi-realm/protocol/openid-connect/token"

# Initialize KeycloakOpenID
keycloak_openid = KeycloakOpenID(
    server_url=f"{KEYCLOAK_SERVER_URL}",
    client_id=KEYCLOAK_CLIENT_ID,
    realm_name=KEYCLOAK_REALM,
    client_secret_key=KEYCLOAK_CLIENT_SECRET,
    verify=True
)



Possible Issues
From the configuration and logs you shared, I expect mainly two problems.

Can't connect to server (Invalid URL.. No scheme supplied and KEYCLOAK_SERVER_URL = "localhost:8080" <- You did not add http scheme to the url.
Your keycloak container might be bound with localhost which is localhost of that container. (Depending on your environment variables of the keycloak container)

Suggested Solutions

Bind 0.0.0.0 to your keycloak container -- maybe using environment variables like KC_HOSTNAME="0.0.0.0" 0.0.0.0 ip address will accept inbound connections.
Now that your keycloak container is accepting connections, you can use http://localhost:8080.
When connecting from a container to keycloak container, you can use the container name as the hostname (as you already tried). For example, http://keycloak:8080

